# How to serialize only fileds with public accessors with jackson 2.5.X?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I need to define an ObjectMapper globally serialize/deserialize objects and I need only fields with the public getters and setters will be serialized.

It could be great if there exists something like:

```
objectMapper.setVisibilityChecker(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
    .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
    .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
    .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
    .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

but with "and" and not "or".

Any idea to do that?

PS: I could do it with annotations, but I need to do it globally.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the success of the question I have been forced to seek a solution by myself. It's not a ideal solution, but it is enought for me.

```
private void configureObjectMapper(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter) {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // Only serialize fields with both public accessors
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS, true);
        // If a field is not found, then ignore it and continue processing, with no fail
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    }
```

Regards!